# Laravel sending e-mails to new registered users

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-7

I'm trying to send e-mails to new users. I made changes in my env. file. I am using a gmail.com mail service. I want to send e-mails to users including their name. Ex:
Hi John, your registration is succesful!
Here John part will be user name.

my code is here in RegistrationController:

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);

        $to_name = $data['name'];
        $to_email= $data['email'];

        $body =[];
        $mailData=array('body'=>$body);

        Mail::send('email.email-register', $mailData, function($message) use ($to_name, $to_email ){
            $message->to($to_email, $to_name)->subject('Registration is succesfull!');
            $message->from(env('MAIL_USERNAME'));
        });
        return $user;

    }
```

Also i am using a mail template. I want to send user as variable to the view. How do i do that?

Comment: You are passing the $mailData array. Try to pass the user there.

Comment: FIrst off, You should with a request instead of a data array. It makes validation of the data possible so you know for sure that the fields are not empty. Apart from that i think it should be fine. Can you maybe dd(); the variables to check if they are set

Comment: Thank you @Chuy it worked ! when i clicked on the passed data on view page it says resource:null that's why i confused. Thanks a lot to everyone!

Answer (score 1):

1- You need to run command `php artisan make:mail RegisterMail`

2- Add Library use `App\Mail\RegisterMail`;
Mail::to('YourEmail@gmail.com')->send(new RegisterMail($mailData));

3- Create a new Data Member in your `App\Mail\RegisterMail.php` Class
public $mailData;
public function __construct($mailData)
{
$this->mailData = $mailData;
}

4- Add this in your `App\Mail\RegisterMail.php`
public function build(){
return $this->from('youremail@gmail.com','your name')->replyTo('youremail@gmail.com')->subject($this->mailData['subject'])->view('email')->with('mailData',$this->mailData);
}